# Ordenar arraylist por dos parametros

Tags: java, arraylist, comparaciones

Tengo en java una clase `Mensaje` con los atributos:

```
String Tipo
int Orden
String Contenido
```

En un `ArrayList` agrego varias instancias de esta clase

El problema surge cuando tengo que ordenarla de tal forma que me queden arriba ordenado afabeticamente por tipo y por orden, he probado con `compareTo` y `Collections.sort()` y no me funcionan nada. Necesito ayuda

Ejemplo de resultado:

Antes de ordenar

```
Tipo Orden Contenido
E    6     aaa
R    2     aaa
E    9     aaa
R    10    aaa
```

Despues de ordenar

```
Tipo Orden Contenido
R    2     aaa
R    10    aaa
E    6     aaa
E    9     aaa
```

Clase mensaje:

```
public class Mensaje {
    int Tipo;
    int Orden;
    String Contenido;

    public Mensaje(int i, int j, String string) {
        Tipo = i;
        Orden = j;
        Contenido = string;     
    }
    public int getTipo() {
        return Tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(int tipo) {
        Tipo = tipo;
    }
    public int getOrden() {
        return Orden;
    }
    public void setOrden(int orden) {
        Orden = orden;
    }
    public String getContenido() {
        return Contenido;
    }
    public void setContenido(String contenido) {
        Contenido = contenido;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    static ArrayList<Mensaje> mensajes = new ArrayList<Mensaje>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mensajes.add(new Mensaje(1, 2, "P01002"));
        mensajes.add(new Mensaje(0, 6, "P01002"));
        mensajes.add(new Mensaje(1, 5, "P01002"));
        mensajes.add(new Mensaje(0, 3, "P01002"));
        imprimir(mensajes);
    }
    private static void imprimir(ArrayList<Mensaje> a){
        for(Mensaje m : a){
            System.out.println(m.getTipo() + " " + m.getOrden() + " " + m.getContenido());
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que no se que clase pone como comparable etc... y los ejemplos de internet no los entiendo

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento de la pagina te invito a dar [tour]

Comment: Añade el código del `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes implementar `Comparable` para definir como comparar dos instancias y luego `Collections.sort(list)` usará tu método para comparar. Por ejemplo, para ordenar primero por `Tipo` y después por `Orden`:

```
public class Mensaje implements Comparable {
    //...
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Mensaje otro = (Mensaje) o;
    int commparacionPorTipo = Tipo.compareTo(otro.getTipo());

    if (commparacionPorTipo != 0)
        return commparacionPorTipo;

    return Integer.compare(Orden, otro.getOrden());
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, simplemente por la versión de java (supongo), tuve que cambiar esta linea
"int commparacionPorTipo = Tipo.compareTo(otro.getTipo());"
por
"int commparacionPorTipo = Integer.compare(Tipo, otro.getTipo());"

Comment: De nada. En tu pregunta, el campo `Tipo` primero está definido como `String` y después como `int`. Mi respuesta se basa en que es de tipo `String` y probablemente estás trabajando con ese campo de tipo `int`. Esa es la razón por la cual tuviste que cambiar esa línea.

Answer (score 0):

Ya sea que lo implementes con la interfaz `Comparable<T>` o proporcionando un `Comparator<T>` a `Collections.sort()` debes definir un orden para comparar los atributos.

Asumiendo 2 objetos `m1` y `m2` de la clase `Mensaje`

- Si primero ordenas por tipo entonces debes realizar:

  ```
  int resultado = m1.getTipo().compareTo(m2.getTipo());
  ```
- Si el resultado es distinto a 0, entonces lo retornas.

  ```
  if(resultado != 0) {
      return resultado;
  }
  ```
- Si es igual a 0, entonces tienen el mismo `Tipo` y debes comparar por el siguiente atributo: `Orden`:

  ```
  return m1.getOrden().compareTo(m2.getOrden());
  ```

Ambas interfaces `Comparable<T>` y `Comparator<T>` retornan int que no es mas que la posicion relativa entre 2 objetos:

- `< 0` si el primero esta antes que el segundo
- `= 0` si tienen la misma posicion
- `> 0` si el primero esta despues que el segundo

Comment: Me ha servido mucho tu ayuda, gracias.